# Passing ASp.net ClientId to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, parameters

I have an ASP.NET page that contains a JavaScript function as follows:

```
function PrintGridView(Title,Address,Terms,GridViewName) {

  if (document.getElementById != null) {
    var html = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl"  xml:lang="en"><HTML>\n\n';

    html += '<head> <title>' + Title + '</title>  <link href="Styles/Print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
    html += ""; 
    html += '</head>';

    html += '<body> <div id="page-wrap">';
    html += '<textarea id="header">'+Title+'</textarea>';
    html += '<div id="identity">';
    html += '<textarea id="address">'+Address+'</textarea>';
    html += '<div id="logo">';

    html += '<div id="logohelp">';
    html +='<input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" /><br />';
    html +='(max width: 540px, max height: 100px)';
    html +='</div>';

    html += '<img id="image" src="images/smallLogo.png" alt="logo" />';
    html +='</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div style="clear:both"></div>';

    var tablerow = GridViewName.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    html += '<table align="center" id="items">';

    var td = tablerow.item(0).getElementsByTagName("th");

    html += '<tr>';  // Get Table Header

    for (var i = 1; i < td.length ; i++) { 
      html +='<th width=auto>'+td.item(i).innerText+'</th>';  
    }

    html += '</tr>';

    //Get Table Rows Data
    if (tablerow.length > 10)
      var Rowlen = 11;
    else
      var Rowlen = tablerow.length -1;

    for (var j = 1; j < Rowlen; j++) {
      html += '<tr class="item-row">';
      var tRow= tablerow.item(j).getElementsByTagName("td");

      for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        html += '<td >' + tRow.item(i).innerText + '</td>';
      }

      html += '</tr>';
    }

    html += '</table>';
    html += '<div id="terms"> <h5>notice</h5> <textarea>'+Terms+'</textarea></div>';
    html +='</div></body></html>';

  }

  var printWin = window.open("", "PrintGridView");
  printWin.document.open();
  printWin.document.write(html);
  printWin.document.close();
  //printWin.print();
}
```

The ASP.NET page is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="Damascus University-Institutes Management System" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/University.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UniPunishmentRewardInfo.aspx.cs" Inherits="InstitutesManagementSystem.RewardPunishmentInfo" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContainerHolder" runat="server">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  //  PrintGridView(Title,Address,Terms,GridViewName) code is here
  </script>

  <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer" runat="server" Width="700px" 
        ActiveTabIndex="0" OnDemand="true" AutoPostBack="false" TabStripPlacement="Top" 
        CssClass="fancy fancy-green" ScrollBars="None" 
        UseVerticalStripPlacement="false" VerticalStripWidth="120px" 
        onactivetabchanged="TabContainer_ActiveTabChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled">


    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanelSendingDownType" runat="server" HeaderText="Typs" Enabled="true" ScrollBars="Auto" OnDemandMode="Once" ViewStateMode="Enabled">

      <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSendingDownType" runat="server" 
             UpdateMode="Conditional">

          <ContentTemplate>
            <table align="center"  class="tabContainerTable" >
              <tr class="tabContainerTableRow">
                <td align="center"  >
                  <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="SendingDownTypeRefreshImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/refresh.png" ToolTip="Refresh" onclick="SendingDownTypeRefreshImageButton_Click"  />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="SendingDownTypePrintImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/printer.png" ToolTip="Print" onclick="SendingDownTypePrintImageButton_Click" OnClientClick="PrintGridView('university',' address','Terms','"<%=SendingDownTypeGridView.ClientID>"')"/>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table> 
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr   class="tabContainerTableRow" >
                <td align="center" class="tabContainerTableCell" ><asp:Label ID="SendingDownResultsLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="tabContainerTableRow"> 
                <td align="center" class="tabContainerTableCell" >
                  <asp:Panel ID="PanelSendingDownType" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" Width="650px">
                    <asp:GridView ID="SendingDownTypeGridView" runat="server" 
                        DataKeyNames="SendingDownTypeID" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#61A6F8" 
                        ShowFooter="True" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
                        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        onrowcommand="SendingDownTypeGridView_RowCommand" 
                        DataSourceID="SendingDownTypeSqlDataSource" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True">

                      <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="???????" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                          <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SendingDownTypeImgBtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/save.png" ToolTip="Update" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SendingDownTypeImgBtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/exit.png" ToolTip="Cancel" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                          </EditItemTemplate>

                          <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SendingDownTypeImgBtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SendingDownTypeImgBtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Remove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/-.png" ToolTip="Remove" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                          </ItemTemplate>

                          <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SendingDownTypeImgBtnAppend" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/+.png" CommandName="Insert" Width="30px" Height="30px" ToolTip="Append" ValidationGroup="Tab1"  />
                          </FooterTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="??? ??? ?????" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">

                          <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="EditSendingDownTypeIDLable" runat="server" CssClass="input" Text='<%#Eval("SendingDownTypeID") %>'/>
                          </EditItemTemplate>

                          <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="ItemSendingDownTypeIDLable" runat="server" CssClass="input" Text='<%#Eval("SendingDownTypeID") %>'/>
                          </ItemTemplate>

                          <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="SendingDownTypeIDTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="3" CssClass="input" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SendingDownTypeIDTextBoxVali" runat="server" ControlToValidate="SendingDownTypeIDTextBox" Text="*" ValidationGroup="Tab1"/>
                          </FooterTemplate> 

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="??? ?????" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">

                          <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="EditSendingDownTypeNameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="input" Text='<%#Eval("SendingDownTypeName") %>'/>
                          </EditItemTemplate>

                          <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="ItemSendingDownTypeNameLable" runat="server" CssClass="input" Text='<%#Eval("SendingDownTypeName") %>'/>
                          </ItemTemplate>

                          <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="SendingDownTypeNameTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="50" CssClass="input"/>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SendingDownTypeNameTextBoxVali" runat="server" ControlToValidate="SendingDownTypeNameTextBox" Text="*" ValidationGroup="Tab1"/>
                          </FooterTemplate> 

                        </asp:TemplateField>
                      </Columns>

                      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#61A6F8" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SendingDownTypeSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlConnectionString %>" 
                     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [SendingDownType_Table] WHERE [SendingDownTypeID] =@SendingDownTypeID" 
                     InsertCommand="IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [SendingDownType_Table]  WHERE [SendingDownTypeID] = @SendingDownTypeID ) INSERT INTO [SendingDownType_Table] ([SendingDownTypeID], [SendingDownTypeName]) VALUES (@SendingDownTypeID, @SendingDownTypeName) ELSE PRINT N'This Type ID Is Exist'" 
                     SelectCommand="SELECT [SendingDownTypeID], [SendingDownTypeName] FROM [SendingDownType_Table] ORDER BY [SendingDownTypeID], [SendingDownTypeName]" 
                     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [SendingDownType_Table] SET [SendingDownTypeName] = @SendingDownTypeName WHERE [SendingDownTypeID] = @SendingDownTypeID">

                      <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SendingDownTypeID" Type="Byte"  />
                      </DeleteParameters>

                      <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SendingDownTypeID" Type="Byte" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SendingDownTypeName" Type="String" />
                      </InsertParameters>

                      <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SendingDownTypeID" Type="Byte" /> 
                        <asp:Parameter Name="SendingDownTypeName" Type="String" />
                      </UpdateParameters>

                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

                  </asp:Panel>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="tabContainerTableRow">
                <td><div class="clear"></div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
  </asp:TabContainer>
```

I try to pass a GridView ID to my JavaScript function that declared as follows:

```
'PrintGridView(Title,Address,Terms,GridViewName)'
```

to use it in my ASP.NET page for `ImageButton` on `OnClientClick` Event as follows:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="SendingDownTypePrintImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/printer.png" ToolTip="Print" OnClientClick="PrintGridView('university',' address','Terms','<%=SendingDownTypeGridView.ClientID%>')"/>
```

but I always get an error. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

*Change*

```
'"<%=SendingDownTypeGridView.ClientID>"'
```

*To*

```
'<%=SendingDownTypeGridView.ClientID %>'
```

Comment: I changed it , But I got Message " Microsoft JScript Runtime Error: Opject dosenot support property or method getElementsByTagName"

Comment: the Answer Is found on this page